# CSS Put all floated elements in middle of main wrapper DIV

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I am trying to align my .homepagewebsitefeatures DIVs so they show in the center of its wrapper `#homepagewebsitefeatures`.

I have tried `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`, but without much luck.

Here is my code:

```css
.homepagewebsitefeaturescontent {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.homepagewebsitefeaturesimage {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.homepagewebsitefeatures {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#homepagewebsitefeatures {
  background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.7);
  padding: 35px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.homepagewebsitefeatures {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  clear: none;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.homepagewebsitefeatureswrap {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepagewebsitefeatures">
  <div class="margin homepagewebsitefeatureswrap">
    <div class="homepagewebsitefeatures">
      <div class="homepagewebsitefeaturesimage">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/tech-support.png" alt="Website Technical Support">
      </div>
      <div class="homepagewebsitefeaturescontent">
        Technical Support
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="homepagewebsitefeatures">
      <div class="homepagewebsitefeaturesimage">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/edit-website.png" alt="Edit website">
      </div>
      <div class="homepagewebsitefeaturescontent">
        Edit your website
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="homepagewebsitefeatures">
      <div class="homepagewebsitefeaturesimage">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/globe-domain-hosting.png" alt="Globe Hosting & UK Domain Name">
      </div>
      <div class="homepagewebsitefeaturescontent">
        UK domain & hosting
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle and please refactor classes to something readable?

Comment: I agree with Senthe, you also need to make it clear what you want. Can you post an image illustrating this?

Comment: Hi I have put a link with the image. I'm trying to get them 3 divs in the middle. http://postimg.org/image/4mb382rmr/full/

Comment: please be specific in what you mean by **middle** - you mean **centered vertically** or **horizontally**??

Comment: Instead of Float:left, try using combination of display:inline-block for bringing the image and content next to each other and then margin: auto for aligning them in center. Better to create a jsfiddle.

Comment: The first rule of centering is "Don't use floats".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have managed to centre them. However how do I evenly space them, can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `#homepagewebsitefeatures` to `display: flex` and use the following CSS attributes for centering content:

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that did not work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have got this to work. However the third .homepagewebsitefeatures shows below the other 2

Comment: @BenAnderson Use `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

Comment: Thanks for that code. I'm trying to space those 3 Divs evenly across the main wrapper #homepagewebsitefeatures

Answer (score 0):

If your `homepagewebsitefeatures` elements are `floated`. In order to get **all of the floated elements centered**(horizontally) you are going to want to make their wrapper, `homepagewebsitefeatureswrap` have auto left and right margins (and `display: inline-block`) and have their parent container, `homepagewebsitefeatures`, have `text-align: center`. Something like so:

```
# homepagewebsitefeatures {
    text-align: center;
}

.homepagewebsitefeatureswrap {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ehghbnru/2/)**

```css
.wrap {
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
 content: '';
    display: table;
}

.container::after {
 clear: both;
}

.float {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.float > span {
 background: red;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="float"><span>float</span></div>
    <div class="float"><span>float</span></div>
    <div class="float"><span>float</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```